# Is it "x degrees North of the equator" or "X degrees north of the equator"?

Tags: capitalization

On many places it is explained quite well: You use a capital letter for wind directions when that indicates a specific place.

> Eg. "I live in the North"

But a small letter, when it goes together with a specific place.

> Eg. "I live in the northern province"..

But what about **"It has a latitude of X degrees n/North of the equator"**?

Comment: If you aren't asking about whether to use x *vs* X then please edit the question title and the bolded sentence so that all x's and X's are shown with the same capitalization.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking. What to use? And preferably also why that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

When you mean the northern part of a country, a region or the world, you can say *the north* or *the North*.

> Birds are migrating from the north.

> Houses are less expensive in the North than in the South.

Looking at the *Corpus of the contemporary American English*, I find 7 sentences containing a phrase similar to "12 degrees north of the equator"; in all of them *north* is not written capitalized, but one of them uses *Equator* instead of *equator*.

> The Arecibo Observatory owes its existence largely to Puerto Rico's political status as a U.S. Commonwealth, and to its geographic position only 17 **degrees north of the Equator**.

*Northern* is an adjective, and it is not written capitalized, except when a word would be written capitalized, or when it is part of an official name, for example in *Northern Ireland*.